# Serilog Network.Sink json output format

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I've been using Serilog to log to local file and it has nice and easy feature to pick output template,

like this:

```
  _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .WriteTo.File(
                      Path.Combine(config.Value.FilePath, config.Value.FileName),
                      outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}",
                      rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day
                  ).CreateLogger();
```

And right now what Iam trying to do is to use Serilog for network logging, like this:

```
    var ip = IPAddress.Parse(config.Value.ServerIp);

        _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .WriteTo.TCPSink(ip, config.Value.Port)
                  .CreateLogger();
```

And If I am logging like this:

```
var message = new { to_index = "test-index", message  = "test-message" };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.Indented);

            log.Information(json);
```

Output on kibana board will look like :

```
{"timestamp":"2020-04-11T10:10:58.1110467+02:00","level":"Information","message":"{\r\n  \"to_index\": \"test-index\",\r\n  \"message\": \"test-message\"\r\n}"}
```

While I would like it to be ONLY object I submitted:

```
{\"to_index\": \"test-index\",\"message\": \"test-message\"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customization of how data gets sent (or rendered) depends on the sink you're using as it's up to the sink to provide you a way to do that.

For example, some sinks allow you to provide an `outputTemplate` string to define the properties, others allow you to provide a class that implements `ITextFormatter` responsible for formatting the messages.

It seems you are using [`Serilog.Sinks.Network`](https://github.com/pauldambra/Serilog.Sinks.Network) which does allow you to provide a custom `ITextFormatter`, so you can implement your own formatter based on one of the default ones ([`CompactJsonFormatter.cs`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/CompactJsonFormatter.cs)and [`RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs)) and decide how the message should be sent.